# How can I use `apply` with a function that takes multiple inputs

Tags: graphlab, sframe

I have a function that has multiple inputs, and would like to use `SFrame.apply` to create a new column.  I can't find a way to pass two arguments into `SFrame.apply`.

Ideally, it would take the entry in the column as the first argument, and I would pass in a second argument. Intuitively something like...

```
def f(arg_1,arg_2):
    return arg_1 + arg_2

sf['new_col'] = sf.apply(f,arg_2)
```

Answer (score 21):

suppose the first argument of function f is one of the column.

Say `argcolumn1` in sf, then

```
sf['new_col'] = sf['argcolumn1'].apply(lambda x:f(x,arg_2))
```

should work

Comment: please replace f with your function name like if you have function named count_imp_words then you will write: products['awesome'] = products['word_count'].apply(lambda x:count_imp_words(x,'awesome'))

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
sf['new_col'] = sf.apply(lambda x : f(arg_1, arg_2))
```

Answer (score 0):

The way i understand your question (and because none of the previous answers are marked as accepted), it seems to me that you are trying to apply a transformation using two different columns of a single `SFrame`, so:

As specified in the [online documentation](https://turi.com/products/create/docs/generated/graphlab.SFrame.apply.html), the function you pass to the `SFrame.apply` method will be called for every row in the SFrame.

So you should rewrite your function to receive a single argument representing the current row, as follow:

```
def f(row):
    return row['column_1'] + row['column_2']

sf['new_col'] = sf.apply(f)
```